# Update trigger on department table that will set the employee to active if the specific department has been deactivated

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have two tables:

`tblEmployees`
`tblDepartment`

I know the codes in the `update`
but I don't know how to insert it to `trigger`.

This is my codes to `update`

```
UPDATE tblEmployees
SET Employee_Type = 'Active'
FROM tblEmployees AS t1
LEFT JOIN tblDepartment AS t2
ON t1.EmployeeID = t2.EmployeeID
WHERE
t2.Department_Type = 'Inactive' AND t2.DepartmentID = '1101'
```

Comment: Do you want to apply trigger on department table?

Comment: Nope, I want to apply trigger in my codes above.

Comment: means whenever an employee type updated which table or data you want to add or insert.

Comment: Oh, sorry my bad, In the employee table.

Comment: review https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25600/Triggers-SQL-Server

Comment: Would `tblDepartment` be better named as "assignment" or something like that? It seems like you're trying to model something along the lines of "an employee is available if they are not currently assigned to a department". Is that the case? If so, there are usually better ways to model it that don't involve storing *redundant* information. (The redundant information *introduces* the opportunity for it to be *inconsistent*)

Answer (score 1):

The trigger would look like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [UpdateEmployeeTrigger] ON tblDepartment AFTER Update
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE e
        SET Employee_Type = 'Active'
        FROM inserted i JOIN
             tblEmployees e
             ON i.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
        WHERE i.Department_Type = 'Inactive'
END;
```

The table layout doesn't make sense.  Why does a table called `Department` have a column called `EmployeeId`?

Answer (score -1):

I hope this could help you create a trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [UpdateEmployeeTrigger]
   ON  tblDepartment
  AFTER Update
AS 
BEGIN

    UPDATE tblEmployees
    SET Employee_Type = 'Active'
    FROM tblEmployees AS t1
    LEFT JOIN tblDepartment AS t2
    ON t1.EmployeeID = t2.EmployeeID
    WHERE t2.Department_Type = 'Inactive'
    AND t2.DepartmentID in (select DepartmentID from inserted)

END
```

This code will get executed after every update on the tblDepartment table and the last line i.e. `t2.DepartmentID = inserted.DepartmentID` will check for that updated record only. If the same record is set to `Inactive`, your `tblEmployee` record will be set to `Active`.

Comment: I got an error,The multi-part identifier "inserted.DepartmentID" could not be bound.

Comment: sorry my mistake!! Updated the answer. It should work now.